# Preprocessor symbol for project type in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, symbols

Is there any pre-defined preprocessor symbol to find current project type in VS2010 that I could use to conditionally compile a piece of code? Currently I'm achieving it by defining my own conditional compilation symbol in project properties, but was wondering if there's a built-in symbol (just like DEBUG and TRACE) that I could use to do the same. For example:

```
#if(WIN_FORMS_PROJECT)
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("WINFORMS");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("CONSOLE");
```

Currently, I've defined my own symbol WIN_FORMS_PROJECT in the WinForms project's symbols, but was wondering if there's a built-in symbol for it and other project types.

Comment: No, there is not... and there are likely better way of achieving what you actually need..

Comment: The code I wrote above is not how I intend to use it. I'm actually applying a set of attributes to some of my classes and methods. But those attributes work only in WinForms projects, not WinCE or Console projects. If u still see better lines of action to achieve that, plz share with the rest of us.

Comment: The fact that you can't apply the same attributes to code used in console project is suspicious - attribuite normally do nothing by themselv... If you really have to share source of classes between not-exactly-compatible runtimes defines/#if are probably ok, especially if you just use them for attributes instead of modifying code.

Comment: Correct. It is simply that I'm applying Editor attribute on one of my classes's ImagePath property. This class is shared between the WinForms and WinCE versions of the project. Now this Editor attribute is defined in normal version of .NET runtime, but not in .NETCF. So the CF project generates a compile-time error. I'm currently tackling it with #if with a conditional symbol in my WinForms project.

Comment: @dotNET Mobile device projects have the `WindowsCE` constant defined, which we use to achieve single-source.

Comment: @Gene. Great. Thanks. Do you know a place from where I could get a list of all these defined symbols for, say VS2010?

Comment: One more option - you can create fake attribute class with the same name yourself and use it in WinCE version so your code compiles in WinCE too without defines...